# how to create a list <> in flutter from Firestore?

Tags: list, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to flutter.
How can I retrieve data from Firestore and form a new profile with every child in my collection? Second question is how can I use this list in another dart file? thank you 
Thank you.

```
final List<Profile> demoProfiles = [
Profile (
photos: [
     "https://",
 ],
name: "abc",

),
Profile (
photos: [
  "https://",

],
name: "abc",

)
 ];
```

[image: Profile.dart]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a firestore strucuture like this:

```
Profile
    photos: []
    name: ""
    age: ""
    distance: ""
    education: ""
```

You can fetch data and build it into your object with this code snippet:

```
fetchData() async{
    final db = await Firestore.instance;
    List<Profile> demoProfiles = []
    db.collection("Profile").get().then(function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach((document) {
            demoProfiles.add(Profile(
                photos: document.data.photos,
                name: document.data.name,
                age: document.data.age,
                distance: document.data.distance,
                education: document.data.education
            ))
        })
    })
}
```

---

Edit:

1) Remove the mockedup list of profiles from your profiles class, it should not be there

2) Edit your mainController to the following:

```
class _MainControllerState extends State<MainController> {

    List<Profile> demoProfiles = [];

    demoProfiles = fetchData();

    Final MatchEngine match Engine = MatchEngine (
        matches:demoProfiles.map((Profile profile) => Match(profile: profile)).toList();
    );

    fetchData() async{
        final db = await Firestore.instance;
        List<Profile> list = [];
        db.collection("Profile").get().then(function(snapshot){
            snapshot.forEach((document) {
                list.add(Profile(
                    photos: document.data.photos,
                    name: document.data.name,
                    age: document.data.age,
                    distance: document.data.distance,
                    education: document.data.education
                ))
            })
        });
        return list;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for helping but I am really new to flutter , viscose returned this error to me . how can I solve this?

The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'.dart(await_in_wrong_context)
'await' applied to 'Firestore', which is not a 'Future'.dartawait_only_futures

Comment: add `async` to the function where you included this code, like this `fetchdata() async { }`, I will edit that into the answer.

Comment: I uploaded some screenshots of the code , can you tell me how to add async correctly ? thanks a lot , you saved me

Comment: The problem is that you placed the code in the wrong class, the code I shared in the answer shoud not be executed on your Profile class, but probably on either your controller, which is more likely, or engine, depending on your app's structure.

Comment: I do not know where I should place your code . I updated the original working code , I want to update the list<profile> with my data in Firestore . how can I do it ?

Comment: I edited the answer and with that you should be able to figure out if something is misplaced.

Comment: Thanks for helping me bother , but I still got some errors after following your code .1.The name 'demoProfiles' is already defined.2.The type of 'demoProfiles' can't be inferred because it refers to an instance method, 'fetchData', which has an implicit type.
Add an explicit type for either 'demoProfiles' or 'fetchData'.3.Only static members can be accessed in initializers.

Comment: I updated the error screenshots on my question , please take a look , thanks